# Android Studioでクラスのメンバとメソッド一覧を表示する方法

Tags: android-studio

macでAndroid Studioを起動した時に、選択しているクラスのメンバとメソッド一覧を表示する方法またはショートカットキーはありますか?
`Android Stuido` -> `Preference` -> `Keymap`
は参照しましたが、該当するキーを見つけられませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

※追記：キーを勘違いしていたので修正しました。
`⌘ (Command) + F12` でメンバ変数とメンバメソッドの一覧をポップアップさせることができます。
`⌘ (Command) + Shift + H` でメソッドヒエラルキーの表示を行います。

これでいかがでしょうか？

---

※追記

参考:https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf

上記は IntelliJ IDEA のショートカットキー一覧です。
Android Studio は IntelliJ IDEA をベースに Android 開発環境として特化した IDE なので、大方の keymap が一致します。
今後の参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: windowsのショートカットだと思いましたが、試しに`Command + F12`を押したところ、メンバ変数とメンバメソッドの一覧を表示させることができました。

Comment: @Markfour すみません、Command キーと Control キーを勘違いしておりました。(しかも typo…) 修正し、参考の keymap も載せておきましたのでご参考にどうぞ。